# How to achieve r value 1.0 with Linear slope angle 10° in R

Tags: r, correlation, linear-model, regression-coefficients

I have been reading about the `r value` and its purpose, however the below image has altered my understanding(that r value represents **Direction** and **Strength** and also **Slope Angle**).

The Wikipedia image below proves that **Slope Angle** cannot be determined from the `r value` at all.

[image]

My problem is that I cannot seem to produce a scatter plot with a perfect `r value 1.0` other than in a *45°* angled slope.

Here is some **R** code to illustrate.

```
a = 1:100
b = 401:500
plot(b,a)
plot(b,a)
```

Image of result of code on the left and my goal on the right.

[image]

**How can I produce a 10° slope with 4 value 1.0?**

---

**@kjetil b halvorsen**
When you say "you must use a plot with equal scales on x and y-axes!"

Both variables a,b contain exactly 100 components, wouldn't that create equal axes?

**@whuber**
Doing what you advised produces a slope with a 45° angle, see below

```
slope = .82
a = 1:100
b = slope * a
plot(a,b)
```

[image]

Comment: To get the correct angle, you must use a plot with equal scales on x and y-axes! In R, use `library(MASS)`  and the `eqscplot()`.

Comment: Pick a number not equal to $1$ or $0$.  Call it `slope`.  Replace the second line of your code by `b <- slope * a`.  Replace the third line by `plot(a,b)`.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen you can do that with base `graphics` `plot`, just set the aspect ratio `asp = 1`

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Following @whuber comments,

```
slope = 3 #choose whatever you want here 
#remember atan(slope) equals the degree of the slope in radians (thanks to @GermanDemidov)
a = 1:100
b = slope*a
plot(a, b, asp = 1) #`asp = 1` keeps the aspect ratio between axes fixed, so the visual effect is evident
```

And a quick example:

[image]

Comment: worth to mention:`slope = 3` should be a `tan` of your desired angle. in this case, `slope = tan(pi / 18)`.

Comment: @GermanDemidov Yeah, you're completely right, I'll mention that in the answer :)